# Match Button Greyed Out in Interactive Rematch Window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geocoding, file-geodatabase, address

I used ArcGIS 10.3.1 and built a composite address locator from 5 address locators. All locators are in the same file gdb. I geocoded addresses in a table within the same file gdb and tried to rematch unmatched results. For some of the results there is a 100 score candidate after I fixed the address string. But the match button (as well as the rematch button) was greyed out so I am not able to rematch this address with the candidate. A screenshot of my rematch window is as below:[image]

Comment: Seems like I can answer this myself now. I end up with finding **the 100 scored candidate is a record with no geometry** in the feature class. I used that feature class to build my address locator. I finally picked a location manually from the map. It really took me a while to figure it out so I think it might be helpful for people coming across similar problems. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try unmatching the address first, it could already be matched. I've attached two screen grabs to show what I mean.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84307)

Comment: I think it does provide an answer, it just might not be the right one ;). Anyway I've added pics to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the thought! But this address has not been matched at the first time.